# Uninstall Sublime Text 2

Tags: windows-7, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I'm upgrading from Sublime Text 2 to Sublime Text 3 on my Windows 7 PC. Add/Remove Programs does not have any entries for Sublime Text. How do I remove Sublime Text 2 completely, including removing the "Open with Sublime Text 2" entry from the Explorer context menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a file named `unins000.exe` in the Sublime Text 2 folder. Run that and it will self-destruct the folder and all registry entries (which includes the Explorer context menu entry).

Comment: Where is the folder?

Comment: @Petah By default,  `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2`